# Do battlemasters in wow-classic (or wow) ever engage in combat?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, world-of-warcraft-classic

In Stormwind, at least, the battlemasters (i.e. the NPCs that will queue you for battlegrounds) never attack Onyxia's dragonkin, so I'm assuming combat with NPCs is not possible (under normal circumstances). I wonder if they can be engaged by Horde? I've not yet made it Horde side to try this out myself...

Lazy Battlemasters! But I assume this is so that BG queues are uninterrupted. There's also the possibility that this was not always the case in Vanilla I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do attack horde players, however they are just scripted not to interact with quest mobs such as the onyxia attunement chain.